# Hide a Div class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a div class with `jQuery` but the code below it doesn't work

```
$("div[class*='test1'] input").hide();
```

Comment: it will hide your textbox, not the div. share the html also

Comment: Can you post the html as well. so that question will be more specific

Comment: Could you show the HTML part that you want to hide?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.test1').hide();
```

or if you want to "wildmask" clases that start with test1

```
$("[class^=test1]").hide();
```

Examples how jQuery selectors work:

$("#lastname")  The element with id="lastname"

$(".intro") All elements with class="intro"

$("h1,div,p")   All `<h1>`, `<div>` and `<p>` elements

$("p:first")    The first `<p>` element

Etc.

Comment: `[class*='test1']` selects elements whose class contais the string 'test1'. Maybe that was a valid intention of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your script will hide input element inside div.
To hide div, remove input from selector
`$("div[class*='test1']").hide()`

Comment: @toto I tried it in fiddle and it worked. Please share your HTML